# Applied to several internal postings, send email to hiring manager?

Tags: applications, human-resources, email, internal-transfer

I have recently been given the OK by my boss to apply to other departments in the same company. I have applied to a few different positions in the past few days and I am just playing the waiting game at this point. Should I just wait for a call and see what happens? Some people have suggested me to email the hiring manager directly (same company so I have access to all of their contact info but I do not know the manager personally) to express my interest. Is that a good idea? I do consider myself well-qualified for all positions I have applied to and the last thing I would want is for HR to filter out my resume for stupid reasons. If I do send this email how should I go about structuring it? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: The internal application process is very different from company to company. We can not tell you if badgering HR is good, bad or irrelevant in your specific company.

Answer (score 2):

Sending an email and expressing your interest is definitely a good idea. Some managers do respond to enthusiastic candidates and would ask the HR to rope in the candidate for the role. They are as well looking for talent to match their needs. If you have it then they would definitely consider.

Dear Bob,

I happened to find the position Y listed on our job portal. I am very much interested in this position as (reasons). I would like to request you to consider my candidature for this position. Looking forward to hearing from you. Thanks

Regards,
X